# configure realmd to allow login without domain name

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to configure realmd to allow users to login via a domain without specifying it?

I've used the "fully-qualified-names = no" option so that usernames don't show the domain name, but they still need to enter the domain (e.g. "user@domain.foo.com") to log in. Ideally I'd like the log in to check local users first, and then try the domain if it fails.

I'm using gnome user chooser on a Debian (jessie) based system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changes made to `realmd.conf` only take affect when joining a domain or realm.

You'll need to either leave and join the domain again, or make the requisite changes to `winbind` or `sssd`.

For example, with `sssd`, you would edit `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` and set `use_fully_qualified_names` to `false`.

If you want to add the default domain suffix so you don't have to type @contoso.com every time you type your username, run

```
sed -i '/nss,/a default_domain_suffix = CONTOSO.COM' /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

Comment: Thanks - with the change made to the sssd.conf it seems to be working partly as expected. I think some of the issue might have been that we were using the 'testing' distribution.

Comment: Confirmed works with CentOS 7

Comment: What would happen if there are also local users on the machine? Would it first check the AD and then check local accounts or vice versa (ok), or would it deny access to local users (not ok), or would local users have to prefix/suffix their username to login (also ok)?

Answer (score 2):

i did this and working as expected as like login-formats: %U

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/use_fully_qualified_names = True/use_fully_qualified_names = False/g' /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

sudo systemctl restart sssd.service

sudo systemctl status sssd.service
```